# Mongo Input in Pentaho Kettle

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, kettle

Is it possible to use named parameters from command line in Mongo Input Query tab? If yes, how? 
Below is what I am trying to achieve but it is not working.

```
{endDate: {$gte : {$date : "${curr_date}"}}}
```

and from command line I am giving the input as below:

```
mongo_date=$(date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')


./pan.sh -file='ds_mongo.ktr'  "-param:curr_date=\`$mongo_date\`" -Level=Basic > /.../tr_get_command_line_arguments.err.log
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `MongoDB Input` allows dynamic queries via variables. In that case I would build the query string in a previous transform and store it in a Job variable for use in this step. Then the job would need to be launched with `kitchen.sh` (instead of pan).

It would look something like this:

First, the job.
[image: MongoQuery.kjb]

Then the transform to build the query string. The query string template is in the `Add Constants` step and looks like this `{endDate: {$gte : {$date : "mongo_date"}}}`.
[image]

Finally the `MongoDB Input` step.
[image]

Note, I do not have Mongo and have never used it, so I don't really know what the the query should look like. Never the less using this technique, the steps above produce the following query to send to Mongo: `{endDate: {$gte : {$date : "03/28/1967 00:00:00"}}}`. I'm guessing that's right, but you may have to modify the query syntax if it isn't. I've used this technique several times to build dynamic queries from parameters.